# SQL Query using a JOIN to select from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query in PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT * from customer c JOIN commsone_phonelines b where b.phone_number LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' AND ";
    $sql.="c.company like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.forename like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.surname like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="CONCAT_WS(' ',c.forename, c.surname) LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.phone like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.accountnumber like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.customerid like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.voip_account like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="REPLACE(c.postcode,' ','') LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="REPLACE(c.postcode,'',' ') LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
    $sql.="c.postcode LIKE '%".str_replace(' ','',$_POST["search"])."%' ";
    $sql.=" AND c.resellerid = '' ORDER BY company ASC";
```

i am basically, trying to select from two different tables and i need to echo information only from the customer table.

If something is found in the `commsone_phonelines` table, it should link `commsone_phonelines.customer_seq = customer.sequence`

**UPDATE:**

I have just run this Query:

```
SELECT c.* from customer c INNER JOIN commsone_phonelines b ON c.sequence = b.client_seq where b.phone_number LIKE '%boat%' OR c.company like '%boat%'
```

it is returning rows from the customer table which is correct, however it shows the same row 5 times

Comment: What does "OR REPLACE(c.postcode,'',' ') LIKE" do? And how might it differ from the line below it?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I find this easier to read...

```
 $sql="
 SELECT c.* 
   FROM customer c 
   JOIN commsone_phonelines b 
     ON b.customer_seq = c.sequence
  WHERE b.phone_number                         LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
    AND ( c.company                            LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.forename                           LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.surname                            LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR CONCAT_WS(' ',c.forename, c.surname) LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.phone                              LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.accountnumber                      LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.customerid                         LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR c.voip_account                       LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%' 
       OR REPLACE(c.postcode,' ','')           LIKE '%{$_POST['search']}%'
        )
    AND c.resellerid = '' 
  ORDER 
     BY company ASC";
```

Comment: doesnt help me tho "/

Comment: i can search for rows in commsone_phonelines and it returns the correct data from the customer table but i cannot search the customer table now

Comment: Ok, i just changed your JOIN to LEFT JOIN and it works fine! :)

Comment: A LEFT JOIN? But you're not selectng any columns from the RIGHT table !?!? (and "`WHERE b.phone_number`" renders  it an INNER JOIN anyway) Still, whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

*....I need to echo information only from the customer table.*

Then select columns of customer table only.

```
$sql="SELECT c.* from customer c JOIN commsone_phonelines b where b.phone_number LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' AND ";
```

Rest of query remains same.

Edit

```
 $sql="SELECT DISTINCT c.col1,c.col2,c.col3 from customer c JOIN commsone_phonelines b where b.phone_number LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' AND ";
```

Comment: if i search for a row in commsone_phonelines it shows the row from the customer table but multiple times. then if i search for a row in the customer table it shows nothing

Comment: do you have an example ?

Comment: see edit .. replace col1,col2,col3 nad so on with actual column names of customer table

Comment: thats working - how can i ensure if i search for a row in the commsone_phonelines it will match commsone_phonelines.customer_seq = customer.sequence ?

Comment: To get exact match use INNER JOIN

Comment: changed to $sql="SELECT DISTINCT c.company, c.accountnumber, c.resellerid, c.title, c.forename, c.surname, c.phone from customer c INNER JOIN commsone_phonelines b ON c.sequence = b.client_seq where b.phone_number LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' "; but its now only showing rows if it matches in commone_phonelines. i want it to show if the customer.sequence does not have a row in commsone_phonelines.client_seq too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57983/discussion-between-mmhasannn-and-user3815283).

Comment: Then u can use LEFT JOIN ... `SELECT DISTINCT c.company, c.accountnumber, c.resellerid, c.title, c.forename, c.surname, c.phone from customer c LEFT JOIN commsone_phonelines b ON c.sequence = b.client_seq `

Comment: this does the same thing - not showing rows that dont exist in commsone_phonelines

Comment: LEFT JOIN shows ALL rows from table present left side of join , in this case it is the customer table ...

Comment: I have this: SELECT DISTINCT c.company, c.accountnumber, c.resellerid, c.title, c.forename, c.surname, c.phone from customer c LEFT JOIN commsone_phonelines b ON c.sequence = b.client_seq where b.phone_number LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";
 $sql.="c.company like '%".$_POST["search"]."%' OR ";